# seqlPro Export and import error : Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'

Tags: mysql

I exported database from seqlpro, then import it and then it throws the bellow error

```
Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.
```

Answer (score 1):

While exporting you have several options, some of which are selected by default by mysql pro... I unchecked a option "Convert Output BLOB fields as hex" and then it worked